# Hibernate mapping error?

Tags: xml, hibernate

I've created a hbm.xml file but it's giving me an error:

> The content of element type "class" must match "(meta*,subselect?,cache?,synchronize*,comment?,tuplizer*,(id|composite-id),discriminator?,natural-id?,(version|timestamp)?,(property|many-to-one|one-to-one|component|dynamic-component|properties|any|map|set|list|bag|idbag|array|primitive-array)*,((join*,subclass*)|joined-subclass*|union-subclass*),loader?,sql-insert?,sql-update?,sql-delete?,filter*,resultset*,(query|sql-query)*)".

Here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
  "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>

    <class name="edu.byu.training.domain.ProductFlsko" table="PRODUCTFLSKO" schema="GAATTRAINING">
        <property name="productId" column="PRODUCT_ID"/>
        <property name="product" column="PRODUCT"/>
        <property name="description" column="DESCRIPTION"/>
        <property name="price" column="PRICE"/>
        <property name="rowNumber" column="ROW_NUMBER"/>

        <query name="get.By.Id" cacheable="true">
            select ProductFlsko
            from edu.byu.training.domain.ProductFlsko prod
            where prod.productId = :id
        </query>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I can't figure this out for the life of me...

Comment: I too had the same error in my `xml`. But my problem was that I had 2 `<ID>` tags. Deleted one of them and solved the problem. Thought it will be useful for others who face the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class mapping must contain an id or composite-id, see [Identifiers](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/manual/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id) in the documentation.

Your id is probably productId.

There are several [identity generators](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/manual/en-US/html/mapping.html#d0e5459).

```
<class name="edu.byu.training.domain.ProductFlsko" table="PRODUCTFLSKO" schema="GAATTRAINING">
    <id name="productId" column="PRODUCT_ID">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="product" column="PRODUCT"/>
    <property name="description" column="DESCRIPTION"/>
    <property name="price" column="PRICE"/>
    <property name="rowNumber" column="ROW_NUMBER"/>

    <query name="get.By.Id" cacheable="true">
        select ProductFlsko
        from edu.byu.training.domain.ProductFlsko prod
        where prod.productId = :id
    </query>
</class>
```

Comment: Oh, right.  Haha, I already solved this problem yesterday but had to revert some files and I completely forgot about it.  Doh!

Comment: Thanks I had the same problem of not configuring any ID. Bingo your suggestion saved my day.